# using grep to search

Tags: grep

Hey guys I was just curious to see if someone could help me.
I'm trying to search a directory recursively to find a file that has .poem as the extension and contains "I" in it.

when I do

```
grep -r -e --include *.poem I
```

I get nothing to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep --include "*.poem" -R I .
```

Comment: how would i add a certain directory? with like 3 sub directories?

Comment: Change `.` to that directory; use `--include-dir`.

Comment: sweet thanks! much appreciated! i always seem to forget the . or directory i want to search

Answer (score 1):

To return the filenames only:

```
 grep -r -H "I" yourdir --include *.poem | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -u
```

Replace yourdir by the directory.